# What's the meaning of denoting $\ell^p$ as $\ell^p(\mathbb{N})$?

Tags: notation, lp-spaces

What's the meaning of denoting $\ell^p$ as $\ell^p(\mathbb{N})$?

I read that it's like $\ell^p$ "over $\mathbb{N}$". But $l^p$ is sequences indexed by $\mathbb{N}$.

So it seems weird to treat the index set as an input to $\ell^p$? Since if $x_n$ is a function, then it could have much more as input or domain than $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: You could also have $\ell^p(\mathbb{Z})$, or $\ell^p(I)$, where $I \subset \mathbb{N}$, no?

Comment: @the_candyman Sure but I was confused at first when seeing $\ell^p(\mathbb{N})$. Because I thought that it's different than $\ell^p$.

Answer (score 2):

Because, given a set $X$, $\ell^p(X)=L^p(X,\mathcal{P}(X),\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is the counting measure (that is, $\Omega(A)=\#A$).

Answer (score 0):

You can define $\ell ^p$ to be a space of sequences with any set of indices (usually it is $\mathbb{N}$), so the space is depended on the set of indices.

Comment: But it is dependent on the function of $x_n(x)$ as well?

Comment: No. It is depended only on the set of indices. Given a set of indices $I$, the space $\ell^p(I)$ is well-defined as the space of all sequences $(a_i)_{i\in I}$ satisfying $\sum_{i\in I}|a_i|^p<\infty$